# Coordinating privilege as a verb

Tags: coordinating-conjunctions

Simple question, I'm sure, but I'm having trouble finding an answer.

I'm writing a methodology and want to say "I will privilege [this theory] over [another]."

I can't find any instances of the preposition "over" coordinating privilege as a verb. Please advise if this usage is correct, or if there is an alternative way of stating the above.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 3):

Here is Merriam-Webster's definition of the verb [*privilege*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/privilege#h2) (emphasis mine):

> **2** : to accord a higher value or superior position
>   // to *privilege* one mode of discourse **over** another

Answer (score 2):

From Nassim Taleb's *The Black Swan*:

> When these ideas and crisp constructs inhabit our minds, we **privilege them over other less elegant objects**, those with messier and less tractable structures (an idea that I will elaborate progressively throughout this book)

The usage seems established, if somewhat uncommon.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably say, "I will favor X over Y."

Comment: I agree. I have never seen privilege used in this way.